# IIS7 Forcing IE7 Mode with no response header or web.config settings

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, internet-explorer-7

We have one server that is forcing IE7 mode in IE8 and IE9. I've checked the HTTP Response Headers and we do not have an X-UA-compatible header set. Nor do we have customHeaders configured in our web.config. When we run our app on any developer's machine or on our development server IE8 and IE9 render our app in IE8 and IE9 mode respectively.

Is there some other setting we're missing that could force IE7 mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably due to the "Display Intranet Sites in Compatibility View" setting, that is defaulted to on for IE.  Go to Tools->Compaitbility View in IE on the developer machines and turn it off to see if that is the problem.

Comment: I don't think this is it. I can open two tabs in the same instance of IE and see the correct mode when running the app from my dev machine or the dev server, and IE7 when running the app from the QA server (the one with the problem).

Comment: If the QA server is identified as a machine that is in the "intranet" either explicitly or through "Automatically Detect Intranet Network" then it will default to intranet (even if it displays "Trusted Site") and it will display in IE7 Compatibility View by default.  I'd try it anyways, it sounds like the exact problem that our QA was having.  If it doesn't work, you're out about 15 seconds of effort.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a look from that angle on Monday.

Comment: @Craig M - No problem... it's a frustrating "default" setting for a developer.